# JPA/Hibernate - mapping keys of Map<EnumType, ...> to the fixed column set in the same table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the entity similar to the following:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Map<ShippingOption, BigDecimal> shippingCost;

    ...

}

public enum ShippingOption {
    STANDARD,
    EXPRESS,
    ...
}
```

I want to map it to the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id                     BIGINT NOT NULL,
    standard_shipping_cost NUMERIC,
    express_shipping_cost  NUMERIC,
    ...
)
```

(note that I don't want to create another table to hold `shippingCost` map entries)

So I can query it something like this (JPQL):

```
SELECT p
FROM Product p
WHERE p.shippingCost[:shippingOption] BETWEEN :lowerBound AND :upperBound
```

resulting in the following SQL when `shippingOption` is set to `STANDARD`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
WHERE p.standard_shipping_cost BETWEEN ... AND ...
```

Is it possible in JPA/Hibernate (maybe using custom types and/or converters)?

Comment: so you expect this Map field to be somehow stored in a "NUMERIC" column?! Or in several columns ? You could use an AttributeConverter to store it in 1 column. But not in multiple. If you want it in multiple then you need to redesign your model